# Twilio 2.7.2 Programmable Video Camera Stays On

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have had a nightmare of a time attempting to stop the video tracks and turn off the camera.  Can ANYONE tell me what I am missing here?  Snippet below is the event handler for when a room is disconnected.  The code executes fine, but the camera stays on.  Thanks in advance.

```js
this.roomObj.once('disconnected', (room: Room, error) => {
      // if (error) {
      //   console.log(`An error has occurred with the room connection: ${error}`);
      // }
      room.localParticipant.tracks.forEach(publication => {
        publication.track.stop();
        const attachedElements = publication.track.detach();
        attachedElements.forEach(element => {
          element.stop();
          element.remove();
        });
        
        room.localParticipant.videoTracks.forEach(video => {
          const trackConst = [video][0].track;
          trackConst.stop(); // <- error
          trackConst.detach().forEach(element => {
            element.stop();
            element.remove();
          });
          room.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(trackConst);
          
        });
        let element = this.remoteVideo1Container.nativeElement;
        while (element.firstChild) {
          element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
        }
        let localElement = this.localVideo.nativeElement;
        while (localElement.firstChild) {
          localElement.removeChild(localElement.firstChild);
        }
        //this.router.navigate([‘thanks’]);
      });

    }, (error) => {
      alert(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: I'm looking into a similar issue, I think that stopping the tracks isn't enough to stop the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I triggered a full page redirect to shut off the camera with `window.location.replace` rather than using `react-router-dom`'s `<Redirect to={} />` to fully shut off the camera.  This may not be possible in your case, and there maybe a better solution.

If you could use the same route that you were going to anyway.  If you weren't planning on changing page, though my solution won't be of much use.

But having an issue with shutting off the desktop camera light in react, I figured I would share my solution.  I can delete or remove this post if this answer displeases anyone or once a Twilio rep (or some mystery person) comes by with a better response.